# Can $S^3$ be distinguished from spaces like $S^2\times S^1$ or $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ using only the number of holes and connectedness

Tags: topological-groups, visualization

I am trying to have a mental picture of topological spaces like $S^3, T^3$ etc. I know about fact that the topological invariants are the essential tools to do this. But the topological invariants like homology, cohomology, etc. are not easily imaginable. I would rather identify the nature of a topological space by simple parameters like number of holes(I can imagine holes of different dimensions, say, a two dimensional hole is a disc removed from a 2d plane, a three dimensional hole is like a water bubble in a pond of water etc.)

I understand it would be difficult to uniquely identify a space using the number of holes alone, but I don't want a unique identification, but rather identifying from at least usual kind of spaces. Say I want to differentiate a $S^3$ from $S^2$ in a sense that whether $S^3$ has any hole or not, if it has, what is the dimensionality of the hole, etc.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of the fundamental group? Arguably it is easy to image and would help you distinguish the three spaces you mention. As for 'number of holes', I don't know how to define that rigorously without some sort of homology.

Comment: Yes, I hope I know it. I understand the fundamental group as a way to identify the simply connectedness, for example if the fundamntal group is trivial, then the space is simply connected etc.